# Search and remove pattern in html php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I am trying to remove a piece of text from a string, but the text has a variable in the middle that makes it hard to make a match, how can I make a variable search and delete with PHP?

The text is `"<div class="about_us_item"><h2>Privacy Policy</h2><div>::cck::34::/cck::<br>::introtext::<h3>Introduction</h3><p>John Blogs respects the privacy of each Visitor."`

The part that needs to be stripped is `"::cck::34::/cck::<br>::introtext::"` but the `"34"` is the variable as it is an ID, so it could be `"::cck::203::/cck::<br>::introtext::"`

I have tried:

```
$html='"<div class="about_us_item"><h2>Privacy Policy</h2><div>::cck::34::/cck::<br>::introtext::<h3>Introduction</h3><p>John Blogs respects the privacy of each Visitor."';
$regex='/::cck::*::/cck::<br>::introtext::/';
preg_match ($regex,$html,$matches);
echo $matches;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please put your attempts at the problem in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if your pattern only changes by the id value:

```
$result = preg_replace('/::cck::([0-9]+)::\/cck::<br>::introtext::/', '', $text);
```

- The `[0-9]+` matches 1 or more digits ranging from `0-9`
- The `\/` escapes the regex delimiter (or you can change the delimiter to something else)

Update: [A working example](http://codepad.org/7afbP43z)

Comment: Thanks, I tried this too, but still showing... driving me nuts

Comment: I have tried again, still no luck... I am wondering if it could be some kind of carridge return I am not seeing or something like that, I will keep on trying, thanks for your help

Comment: @user2597255 is the output in my link what you want?

Comment: ok got it! preg_replace('#::cck::(.*)::/cck::(.*)::introtext::#U', '', $about_html_item); Thanks for your help @AlexP